# ALT + TAB is not working after displaying MessageBox on modal dialog

Tags: c#, windows, modal-dialog, messagebox

**ALT + TAB is not working after displaying MessageBox on modal dialog...**

I've three projects (P1, P2 and P3) under one solution file. P1 contains P1Form.cs, P2 contains P2Form.cs.

**Detail of these files are as follow:**

P1Form.cs contains one button which shows the Message box from `MessageBox.Show()` method. 
P2Form.cs contains one button which shows the Message box from `MessageBox.Show()` method.

Project P3 contains 3 forms Form_A, Form_B and Form_C. 
Form_A is the MDI container and has one button which opens the Form_B as its child form. Form_B has also one button which open the Form_C as modal dialog from ShowDialog() method.

**Form_C is inherited from P2Form.cs and P2Form.cs is inherited from P1Form.cs.**
Form_A.cs is the Main form which will be the first form for application.

**Steps to Reproduce desired issue:**

1. Open the Form_A which is the MDI
   Container
2. Click on button which will open the
   Form_B
3. Again click the button on the Form_B
   which will open the Form_C which
   will be having two buttons (both buttons are from base classes P1Form.cs and P2Form.cs)
4. Click the any button of Form_C which
   will open the message box.

**Issue:**
Now switch the window through Alt + Tab. You will not be able to see the current windows icon on switching window.

**Alternative options which I tried...**

1. If I use `Form.show()` instead of `Form.ShowDialog`, then it works fine.
2. If I write all messageBox coding in current class instead of writing in base class, then it works fine.

Can anyone suggest me how can I resolve this issue without doing both above mentioned alternatives which I had already tried?

Comment: nice markup of your post, and that for a new user.Thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up a parent-child relationship from Form_B (parent) to Form_C (child):

```
Form_C f = new Form_C();
f.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: Forgot to add the MSDN link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358(VS.71).aspx#Mtps_DropDownFilterText

Comment: Can't you edit your own post? +1 anyway. This is the answer I would give.